# android-add top padding to Chip text

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-chips

I'm using `Chip` component from `material` library in my android app. It is an action chip which has an icon and a text inside. the point is that I need to add some padding to the top of the text in order to bring it down a little a bit.

I have tried to add `textAppearance` style to the chip, but can not find any style item to do what i need. how to do that?!

```
        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:id="@+id/chip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:chipIcon="@drawable/satisfied"
        app:chipIconTint="#444"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="my text!"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Widget.App.Chip" />


    <style name="Widget.App.Chip" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Action">
    <item name="android:textSize">14dp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/xyz</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    // what item is needed to achieve top padding?!
    </style>
```

Answer (score 2):

simply: you can't. `Chip` is designed as is and it extends `AppCompatCheckBox` and further `TextView` (doc [HERE](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/chip/Chip)). so these icons on the left and/or right are [compound drawables](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setCompoundDrawables(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)), not separated `View`s (e.g. `ImageView`s), so every padding you will set to `Chip` will add padding to text and all icons (as this is one `View`). for your purposes you must create own custom `View`, easiest way would be probably to create horizontal `LinearLayout` with childs: `TextView` and `ImageView`s on left and right to it, and then you can set additional padding only for text

Comment: thanks for your explanation. can I extend Chip class and add my desired padding?

Comment: nope, just like in answer: you have to create "own" `Chip`. Extending material's `Chip` won't change fact that all icons and text are using same padding as they are drawn in single `View`

Comment: @snachmsm It is not correct. The `Chip` extends `AppCompatCheckBox` but it is based on `ChipDrawable` which is a `MaterialShapeDrawable`. The text and the icons are **not** compound drawables. @Soheil you have to extend the `ChipDrawable` but most of methods are private.

Comment: right, construction is different as I've described, but still this is a single `View` and `padding` is whole `View`s attribute, so it will be applied for whole content. `Chip` is providing some custom attrs, but I don't see any related to Soheils requirements, and `private` methods are practically preventing extending this class. I'm not saying this is not possible, but this will take a lot of effort (digging in source) and some future lib update may break this modification, so conclusion is the same: best way is to create own `Chip`-styled custom `View`...

Comment: also leaving [`Chip` source link](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/chip/Chip.java) if anyone interested